# @font-face and custom fonts not loading on WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

I am developing a WordPress site locally and cannot get my fonts to load properly. I have taken the same folder of fonts to a plain html website and the fonts loaded correctly. My problem seems to be strictly to this project.

The fonts are in a font folder sitting in my theme folder.
The below code is written on _typography.scss within a sass folder. Sass is compiled to the theme's css folder on the styles.css file.

Following both file paths on the scss and css file bring you to the appropriate file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "computerfontregular";
  src: url("/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.svg#computerfontregular")
      format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

1st error
GEThttp://my-xampp-IP/planet-cruiser/wp-content/themes/planet_cruiser-89/css/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.woff2
Status
404 Not Found
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 1.62 KB (1.28 KB size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request PriorityHigh

2nd error
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "computerfontregular" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://my-xampp-IP/fonts/computer-font/computerfont-webfont.woff2

It repeats this until each type has been called.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may find themselves in this quandary make sure your font folder has been given read & write permissions. I added the fonts folders after the initial setup and that's what was preventing them from loading. I also needed to add "../" to the path.

Edit: Also remember to give those permissions to each individual font folder as well as the "main" font folder they are stored in.